# Bings Search API doesn't always return the same result count

Tags: c#, bing-api

If I do a search with Bings Webservice and search without specifying Offset and Count, I receive 98 results for my search. If I instead uses offset (as shown in the code below) total count is only 18.

Shouldn't the total count be the same if I specify offset or not?

```
    BingService soapClient = new BingService();

    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
    request.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingKey"];
    request.Sources = new BingLiveSearchService.SourceType[] { SourceType.Web };
    request.Query = query;
    request.Web = new BingLiveSearchService.WebRequest { Count = 20, Offset = 21, OffsetSpecified = true, CountSpecified = true };

    string resp = string.Empty;

    var response = soapClient.Search(request);
    if (response.Web != null && response.Web.Total > 0)
    {
        resp += "TOTAL COUNT:" + response.Web.Total + "<br/><br />";
        foreach (var item in response.Web.Results)
        {
            resp += "<div style='padding-bottom:10px;'> + item.Title + "</div>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would think the count should be the same, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some words of warning in [the API Basics documentation](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html): "Depending on how popular a query is, the estimated number of results could be very different from the real number. Do not rely on this number for critical computation". I wonder if the count and offset arguments make the computation take slightly longer and so it is halted before as many results are gleaned? It is also worth note that [the WebRequest.Count Property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251004) mentions that "The minimum value for Count is 1; the maximum value is 50", so if you do specify a value for Count you are going to get less than the 98 results you have seen without specifying Count.